# Make a border with only the corners and space betwen

Tags: wpf, drawing

I don't know how to explain the title but anyone have a idea how can i make the red corners without grid. Only BorderBrush if is possible ?

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

```
                    <Grid>
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF006E8C"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="RenderOptions.EdgeMode" Value="Aliased"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Canvas Width="8" Height="8" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Path Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="1" Data="M0,8L0,0L8,0"/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas Width="8" Height="8" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Path Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="1" Data="M0,0L8,0L8,8"/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas Width="8" Height="8" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Path Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="0" Width="8" Height="8" Data="M8,8L0,8L0,0"/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <Canvas Width="8" Height="8" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Path Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Data="M8,0L8,8L0,8"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
```

Comment: By drawing 8 short lines at the right place.

Comment: I don't know why but the positions is not rendering correctly for Right, Bottom. If RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"

Comment: What exactly do you mean "without grid"?

Comment: My first idea was to make a grid with 2 col 2 rows and put the Paths into it.

Comment: But didn't you say you don't want a grid? And what is "Paths"?

Comment: I edit the post. I try the lines but i think the paths is more easy.

Comment: Your code is using a Grid, but you said you don't want to use one? Is there something currently wrong with your sample code?

Comment: Yes. My question is if anyone knows other operation more good. Like a BorderBrush if is possible to make something like this only for corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using a `Grid`, as your sample code shows, you can use `Border` controls and modify their `BorderThickness` depending on which corner they represent:

```
<Grid>
    <Border
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"
        BorderBrush="Red"
        Width="10" Height="10"
        />
    <Border
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        BorderThickness="0,1,1,0"
        BorderBrush="Red"
        Width="10" Height="10"
        />
    <Border
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        BorderThickness="1,0,0,1"
        BorderBrush="Red"
        Width="10" Height="10"
        />
    <Border
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        BorderThickness="0,0,1,1"
        BorderBrush="Red"
        Width="10" Height="10"
        />
    <TextBlock
        Text="Add"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        />
</Grid>
```